# Using Spark Streaming with Kafka docker container errors?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka docker-compose setting with below `docker-compose.yml` installed in VM-Ware machine.
When I connect to it by `pyspark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils`, it released some errors.
Please help me resolve this problems.
I used configuration from https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    zookeeper:
      image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest"
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ports: 
        - "2181:2181"
  
  # This has three listeners you can experiment with. 
  # BOB for internal traffic on the Docker network
  # FRED for traffic from the Docker-host machine (`localhost`)
  # ALICE for traffic from outside, reaching the Docker host on the 192.168.231.145
  # Use 
    kafka0:
      image: "confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:latest"
      ports:
        - '9092:9092'
        - '29094:29094'
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://kafka0:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://0.0.0.0:29094
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://localhost:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://192.168.231.145:29094
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_BOB:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_FRED:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_ALICE:PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_BOB
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100
  
    kafkacat:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafkacat
      command: sleep infinity
```

**python code i used to connect from vm-ware hosted machine**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from confluent_kafka import Producer, Consumer
import socket
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    sc = SparkContext(appName="Processing_raw_data")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

    in_stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "192.168.231.145:2181", socket.gethostname(), {"testing": 1}, {"auto.offset.reset": "smallest"})

    in_stream.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**Errors**

```
21/06/19 19:44:24 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
21/06/19 19:44:24 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2021-06-19 19:44:27
-------------------------------------------

21/06/19 19:44:27 WARN AppInfo$: Can't read Kafka version from MANIFEST.MF. Possible cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]-------------------------------------------
Time: 2021-06-19 19:44:28
-------------------------------------------

21/06/19 19:44:28 WARN ClientUtils$: Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(testing)] from broker [id:0,host:kafka0,port:29092] failed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:93)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
21/06/19 19:44:28 WARN ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread: [dino-computer_dino-computer-1624106667579-fbe9ab2d-leader-finder-thread], Failed to find leader for Set([testing,0])
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(testing)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka0,port:29092)] failed
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:93)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: 1) If the Spark code runs on the same machine as Docker, don't use IP addresses 2) If you want to connect to Kafka, why are you using the Zookeeper port 3) Spark Streaming is deprecated, so you should be using Structured Streaming API instead

Comment: I have changed createStream method to createDirectStream method and it've just worked! Now, i will read aboud Structured Streaming API as you suggested. Thank you!